# CodeIgniter grabbing variables from other methods inside the same class

Tags: codeigniter

In Ci, how do I grab a variable from another method inside the same class?

Comment: What do you mean by "grab a variable from another method"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to set it as a class variable and use that.

Something like:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    $my_variable = null;

    function _set_myvariable()
    {
        $this->my_variable = "this variable has a value";
    }

    function get_variable()
    {
            echo $this->my_variable; // outputs NULL
            $this->_set_myvariable();
            echo $this->my_variable; // outputs "this variable has a value"
    }
}
?>
```

calling the `get_variable` method will:

1. Call the `_set_myvariable` private function (note the "_" starting the function name) that will set the class variable.
2. Then, it will echo out the value of that variable (which will be "this variable has a value")